# How show title attribute when just we use truncate a big text in vue?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a table, which created dynamically.
I added `truncate` class to span in `td` to be able to make the log sentences shorter and for being able to see the whole sentence I made title for it.
But now I can see the title for all spans. I just need to be able to see titles for spans have `truncate` class. How can I make it?

```js
Vue.component('TheTable', {
  template: `<table class="table">
    <tr
      v-for="(row, i) in data"
    >
      <td
        v-for="(item, index) in row"
      >
        <span
        :title="item"
        class="truncate"
        >
          {{ item }}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>`,
  data() {
    return {
      data: [
        [
          'very very very very very very very very very very very very very very big sentence',
          'very very very very very very very very very very very very very very big sentence',
          'very very very very very very very very very very very very very very big sentence'],
        ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
      ]
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```css
.truncate {
display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.table td {

  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <the-table/>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not related to Vue btw, it's a pure DOM problem

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev, yes I know. but as my code was vue so I tagged it.

Comment: if your data changes you should recalculate also. you could add a watch. but don't forget to update on the next tick to allow Vue to update the DOM. in vue3 i use `nextTick()`. don't know how vue2 handles that, my first code on vue2 in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the need of the title yourself initially and on the window resize. Expand the snippet to see how it works on the resizing:

[image]

It was a fast solution. Some tweaks may be needed in your particular case if the styles change.

```js
Vue.component('TheTable', {
  template: `<table class="table">
    <tr
      v-for="(row, i) in data"
    >
      <td
        v-for="(item, index) in row"
      >
        <span
        class="truncate"
        >
          {{ item }}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>`,
      methods:{
        calcTitles(){
          
          this.$el.querySelectorAll('.truncate').forEach(span => {

            const {display, overflow} = span.style;
            span.style.overflow = 'visible';
            span.style.display = 'inline-block';

            const td = span.closest('td');
            const rectTd = td.getBoundingClientRect();
            const rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
            
            const needsTitle = rect.left - rectTd.left  +  rect.width > td.offsetWidth;

            if(needsTitle){
              span.setAttribute('title', span.textContent);
            }else{
              span.removeAttribute('title');
            }
            
            span.style.overflow = overflow;
            span.style.display = display;
          });
        }     
      },
      unmounted(){
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.calcTitles);
      },
      mounted(){
        this.calcTitles = this.calcTitles.bind(this);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.calcTitles);
        this.calcTitles();
      
      },  
  data() {
    return {
      data: [
        [
          'very very very very very very very very very very very very very very big sentence',
          'very very very very very very very very very very very very very very big sentence',
          'very very very very very very very very very very very very very very big sentence'],
        ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
      ]
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```css
.truncate {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.table td {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <the-table/>
</div>
```